# Norms on $\mathcal{P}_N$ Vector Space of Polynomials up to Order N

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

> $\|p\|_\infty :=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|p(x)|$ and $\|p\|_{L^1}:=\int_0^1 |p(x)| dx$.
>
> As the space of real-valued polynomials on $[0,1]$ up to order $N$ is a $N+1$ dimensional vector space and $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{L^1}$ are norms for it, there is a constant $C_N$ s.t. $\|\cdot\|_\infty \leq C_N \|\cdot\|_{L^1}$.

Is there an easy way how to compute this $C_N$?

Comment: It seems like you are implicitly using the vector space isomorphism with $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$.

In which case the constant is just the same as it would be for $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$.

Namely $C_{N+1}=1$ works, since

$$||x||_{\infty} = \max (|x_i|) \le \sum |x_i| = ||x||_1$$

Comment: Any two norms on a finite-dimensional real or complex vector space are uniformly equivalent.

Comment: @William: No, I don't use such an isomorphism.

Comment: @user254665: Yes, I know that. But as stated in question, I am interested in an explicit value of this constant.

Comment: You're right sorry, I thought you were referring to the 1 norm on Rn, not the L1 norm on the space of integrable functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider the unit sphere under $|| \cdot ||_1$: all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $\int_0^1|p(x)|dx \le 1$.

We have $$\int_0^1 |p(x)| dx \le \int_0^1 \sum |a_i||x^i| dx = \int_0^1 \sum |a_i|x^i dx = |a_0|+\frac{1}{2}|a_1| + \dots + \frac{1}{n+1}|a_n| $$
by the triangle inequality and similar standard inequalities.

Thus, for any polynomial on the L1 unit sphere, we have $$1 \le |a_0| + \frac{1}{2}|a_1| + \dots + \frac{1}{n+1}|a_n|$$

**EDIT:** Compare the upper bound with the value of the infinity norm: $$||p||_{\infty} = \max |a_0+\dots + a_nx^n| \le \max \sum |a_i x^i| \le \sum |a_i| \le (n+1)\left[|a_0| + \frac{1}{2}|a_i| + \dots \frac{1}{n+1}|a_n| \right]$$

These inequalities give us an upper bound for the infinity norm of any polynomial on the L1 unit ball: namely because any polynomial on the L1 unit ball has to satisfy the first inequality, and we can then use the same input data (i.e. the coefficients) to get an upper bound for the infinity norm of that polynomial.

So ideally we are looking for a polynomial which satisfies the first inequality and which attains the upper bound given by the second inequality -- since it attains an upper bound for the infinity norm of a polynomial on the L1 unit sphere, it must be the maximum, and we are done.

If we have a polynomial such that $1=\int_0^1 |p(x)| dx = |a_0| + \dots + \frac{1}{n+1}|a_n|$, then it must be on the $L1$ unit sphere. For any other polynomial on the L1 unit sphere, we have $$||q(x)||_1 < |b_0| + \dots + \frac{1}{n+1}|b_n|$$ which implies that $$||q(x)||_{\infty} < (n+1)\left[ |b_0| + \dots + \frac{1}{n+1}|b_n|\right]$$ which means that it can not attain the maximum for the infinity norm, which means we suffer no loss of generality by ignoring them.

Thus, focusing on polynomials $1=\int_0^1 |p(x)| dx = |a_0| + \dots + \frac{1}{n+1}|a_n|$ will give us a strategy to actually attain the maximum for the infinity norm on the $L1$ unit sphere, because if any such polynomials exist, the upper bound assumes the form: $$||p||_{\infty} \le n+1$$

We get the most "bang for our buck" by trying to maximize the value associated with the $a_n$ term, since it gets reduced by a factor of $n+1$ when calculating the $L1$ norm, the largest reduction factor of any of the terms, while like the remaining terms it is left alone when calculating the $L\infty$ norm.

I.e. I claim that the monomial $(n+1)x^n$ assumes the maximum value of $n+1$ of $L\infty$ on the $L1$ unit sphere. This is clear because the $L\infty$ norm of $(n+1)x^n$ actually attains the upper bound given above for the $L\infty$ norm.

Therefore it follows that $C_N = n+1$. For the idea of the proof and how to generalize the computation, see here: https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf

**EDIT:** $|p(x)| = p(x)$ when $p(x) \ge 0$, $|p(x)|=-p(x)$ when $p(x)<0$, so |p(x)| is piecewise polynomial and the above argument suffers no loss of generality. Also note that the integral will be greatest (at least when we restrict the norm of the polynomials) when there are no changes of sign. So while this does suffer from some lack of details, it is still the right answer.

Comment: I thought the same as you but then I realized that $L^1$ norm is not given by that as you take the absolute value before you integrate. But it's easy to see that you get the correct inequality using the triangle inequality of the integral and noting that $|x^n|=x^n$. 
I guess you can fix it with very little edits.

Comment: Sorry again, it is not so easy to fix. I think it does not work like this.

Comment: The upper bound I gave above still holds I believe, and the given polynomial actually attains that upper bound, so there should be no loss in generality.

Comment: I am very sorry but I still don't see why this should be true. To make the argument work, it seems to me that you need the reversed inequality in your estimate.

Comment: The inequality gives us an upper bound for the infinity norm of any polynomial on the L1 unit sphere

Comment: It seems to give me an upper bound for the $L^1$ norm because you start with $\int |p(x)| dx$.

Comment: I don't want to nitpick at all. I really appreciate your effort and I am sorry if I sound rude. I don't mean to.
My concern was only that for $N=1$ the function $p(x)= 1/2 - x$ also makes the inequality sharp although it is not of the from $(n+1)x^n$.
Do you mean by edit the piece-wise polynomial argument?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not $(n+1)x^n$ is the unique polynomial to attain the upper bound. Uniqueness is not necessary for the argument. We could also use $-(n+1)x^n$ for example. Also I don't understand the purported counterexample, since $2x$ clearly has a larger infinity norm (it equals 2 at $x=1$). Also it's not necessary per se to actually achieve an upper bound in order to show that something is the maximum, but it is certainly sufficient (since then clearly it is the least upper bound, or supremum, or maximum).

Comment: Do you disagree with the claim: "a polynomial which satisfies the first inequality and which attains the upper bound given by the second inequality -- since it attains an upper bound for the infinity norm (given by the second inequality) of a polynomial on the L1 unit sphere (sufficient to satisfy the first inequality), it must be the maximum, and we are done." I will edit the answer again so why this is true might be more clear.

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately, there is a flaw in the proof. For example the polynomial $p(x)=\frac{18}5(x-1/3)$ is on the boundary of the $L^1$ unit ball because $\int_0^1|x-\frac13|dx=\frac5{18}$, but $\frac12|a_1|+|a_0|=3$. The optimal $C_1$ is the maximum of $||q||_\infty$, taken over _all_ polynomials $q$ of degree 1 on the boundary of the unit ball of $L^1$. Now $||p||_\infty=p(1)=\frac{12}5$. Therefore $C_1$ must be at least $12/5$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems difficult to determine the optimal constants $C_n$. Below, I give an upper and a lower bound for them and determine $C_1$. Observe that my claims 2 and 3 contradict the first answer.
Claim 1: $C_n\leq 2(n+1)^2$. 
Given a polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n$, consider its primitive $q(x)=\int_0^xp(t)\,dt$. We have $|q(x)|\leq\int_0^x|p(t)|\,dt\leq||p||_1$ and therefore $||q||_\infty\leq||p||_1$. By [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_brothers%27_inequality) for polynomials, one has $||f'||_{\infty,[-1,1]}\leq n^2||f||_{\infty,[-1,1]}$ for polynomial $f$ of degree at most $n$ on the interval $[-1,1]$. By a scaling, we find $||q'||_\infty\leq2(n+1)^2||q||_\infty$ because $q$ is of degree $n+1$ and considered on $[0,1]$. This yields $||p||_\infty\leq2(n+1)^2||p||_1$.
Claim 2: For odd $n=2m+1$, we have $C_{2m+1}\geq (m+1)(m+2).$
Consider the $(m+1)$-th Legendre polynomial $P_{m+1}$. Except for a factor it is characterized by the fact that $\int_{-1}^1P_{m+1}(x)f(x)dx=0$ for all polynomials of degree $m$ or less. Then consider the polynomial $p(x)=x\,(P_{m+1}'(2x-1))^2$ of degree $2m+1$. It has positive values for $x\in[0,1]$ and attains its maximum at $x=1$ (see Abramovitz/Stegun, formula 22.14.8 and the differential equation for $P_{m+1}$). We have hence $||p||_\infty=(P_{m+1}'(1))^2$. We show that $||p||_1=\frac12P_{m+1}'(1)P_{m+1}(1)$. To do this, we write $P_{m+1}'(2x-1)=P_{m+1}'(1)+(x-1)q(x)$ with some polynomial $q$ of degree $m-1$. Then first integration by parts gives
$$\int_0^1x(x-1)q(x)P_{m+1}'(2x-1)dx=-\frac12\int_0^1\frac d{dx}(x(x-1)q(x))\,P_{m+1}(2x-1)\,dx=0$$ 
since the degree of the derivative is $m$ and therefore
$$||p||_1=\int_0^1x\,(P_{m+1}'(2x-1))^2dx=P_{m+1}'(1)\int_0^1xP_{m+1}'(2x-1)dx=\frac12P_{m+1}'(1)P_{m+1}(1).$$
Here integration by parts has again been used in the last step. Altogether we find that $||p||_\infty/||p||_1=2P_{m+1}'(1)/P_{m+1}(1)$. Again, we use known formulas for the Legendre polynomials: $P_{m+1}(1)=1$, $P_{m+1}'(1)=\frac12(m+1)(m+2)$ and find $||p||_\infty/||p||_1=(m+1)(m+2)$ for our polynomial. Therefore the constant $C_{2m+1}$ has to be at least $(m+1)(m+2)$. This proves the claim.
Since $C_{2m}\geq C_{2m-1}\geq m(m+1)$, this also gives a lower bound for $C_n$, $n$ even.
Claim 3: In the special case n=1, $C_1=\sqrt2+1$. 
Let us first consider $p(x)=x-a$, where $a$ is a constant between 0 and 1/2. Then $||p||_\infty=1-a$ and $\||p||_1=\int_0^1|p(x)|dx=\frac{a^2}2+\frac{(1-a)^2}2=\frac12(1-2a+2a^2)$. We want to minimize the quotient $||p||_1/|p||_\infty=\frac12(\frac1{1-a}-2a)$ as a function of $a$. The minimum is attained for $a$ such that $(1-a)^2=\frac12$ which means $a=1-\sqrt{\frac12}$. For this value of $a$, the quotient equals $\frac12(\sqrt2-2(1-\sqrt{\frac12}))=\sqrt2-1.$ Therefore, for polynomials of the form $p(x)=x-a$, $a$ between 0 and $1/2$, the quotient $||p||_\infty/|p||_1$ is at most $\frac1{\sqrt2-1}=\sqrt2+1$ and this value is actually attained for $a=1-\sqrt{\frac12}$.
Now let $p$ be any polynomial of degree at most 1.
If it is a constant, $||p||_\infty/|p||_1=1$. Otherwise, $p(x)=x+a_0$ except for a constant factor that does not change the quotient.
If $a_0\geq0$, then the quotient is $\frac{1+a_0}{\frac12+a_0}\leq2$.
If $-\frac12\leq a_0\leq0$, then the quotient is at most $\sqrt2+1$ as seen above.
The case $a_0\leq-\frac12$ is reduced to the others by symmetry.
We consider $\tilde p(y)=-p(1-y)=y+\tilde a_0$ with $\tilde a_0=-1-a_0\geq-\frac12.$ Thus the quotient is at most $\sqrt2+1$ in any case and
this value of the quotient is attained for some polynomial as we have seen. This proves $C_1=\sqrt2+1$.